# How to initialize a series of lists with strings in python?

Tags: python

How do I loop over a range of integers, concatenating a string, such as "array" with the iterate of the loop, and initialize a list with the resulting string?  The following single line shows what I want to do, where I get a "can't assign to function call" error.

```
for i in range(int(nmat)): eval('array'+str(i)) = []
```

Meanwhile, further down in the code the following code is accepted (provided I comment out the preceding code that caused it to bomb)

```
eval('array'+str(ct1)).append(array[1:9])
```

However it tells me that the name 'array0' is undefined (since I don't know how to initialize a series of lists in this manner).  Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do that.

Instead of having numerous variables array*i*, use just one: `array`, of type list. For example, if every element of the list should be an empty list:

```
array = [[] for i in range(int(nmat))]
```

You can then access the first element with `array[0]`, the second with `array[1]`, and the number of elements in `array` (`int(nmat)` in this case) with `len(array)`.

Comment: Haha, so essentially python's keeping me from being an idiot.  What you said makes more sense anyway ... once my mind was stuck on that way to do it I couldn't think outside the box.  Thanks.

Comment: `array = [] * range(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`

Comment: @joaquin Oops, that line was indeed totally messed up. Sorry, corrected now: `[[]]` * 3. By the way, there is probably no reason to have empty lists laying around either.

Comment: Your first line of code is just wrong. By doing `array = [[]] * int(nmat)` you're creating references to the same empty list.

Comment: @Franklin yeah, that will lead to problems down the road. Removed.

Answer (score 4):

```
mylist = []
for i in range(10):
    a = ['array%i' %i]
    mylist.append(a)

print mylist


[['array0'], ['array1'], ['array2'], ['array3'], ['array4'], ['array5'], ['array6'], ['array7'], ['array8'], ['array9']]
```

in one line:

```
mylist = [['array%i' %i] for i in range(10)]
```

You must be very careful with list multiplication:

```
>> array = [[]] * int('3')
>> array
[[], [], []]
>> array[0] = 'imastring'
>> array
['imastring', [], []]
```

and still more dangerous:

```
>> array = [[]] * int('3')
>> array[0].append('repeated')
>> array
[['repeated'], ['repeated'], ['repeated']]
```